# DNS for HTTP vs HTTPS

Tags: https, iis-6, load-balancing

I have internal domain DNS for Http i.e. http://companyintanet.dev.local. Do I need a separate DNS entry for https i.e. https://companyintranet.dev.local or one will suffice both.

I'm trying to understand how DNS, Web Server Load Balancer and IIS works in terms of user reqest for http vs https.

Thanks.

Comment: To answer your question: No. DNS resolves a domain not a protocol. This is offtopic here btw.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need a separate DNS entry for https.

You'll have an A record for companyintranet.dev.local. http or https doesn't come into play anywhere here. DNS doesn't care what protocol you're using to connect to a host, all it does is map a name to an IP address.

If you want to enable HTTPS on the server, you'll need to install a certificate and enable a site binding for port 443 (HTTPS) on the server, and tell it to use the certificate for that binding.